# How to enable/disable nested checkboxes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-blade

```
@foreach($description as $key => $value)
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 mb-3">
        <div class="d-block" id="module">
            <input type="checkbox" name="module_access[{{ $key }}]" class="module-checkbox ml-2" value="1">{{ $value['name'] }}
        </div>
        <div class="d-block ml-4 mt-2" id="subModule">
            @if(isset($value['extras']))
                @foreach ($value['extras'] as $index => $extra)
                <input type="checkbox" name="module_access[{{ $key }}][{{ $index }}]" class="sub-module-checkbox ml-2" value="1">{{ $extra }}
                @endforeach
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

I have this piece of code in my Laravel Blade File. I am using jquery (after 4 Years, so need a bit of help out here) to set the checkbox inputs under id #subModule as disabled. (This is working fine)

```
$('#subModule input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled','true');
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is based on the checkbox inputs under id #module, the corresponding submodule checkbox should get enabled/disabled.

[image]

What I have done till now is this but it is still not working

```
$('body').on('click', '#module',function(event) {
  if($('input[name="module_access"]:checked').val() != 1) {
    $('#subModule select option').prop("disabled", false);
}
```

});

Can anyone help me? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `class` selector instead of `id` . Then , on click of `module` checkboxes use `.closest("row").find(".subModule > input[type=checkbox]")` to refer your submodule checkbox and then simply do `attr("disabled", false)` to remove disable.

***Demo Code***:

```js
$('.subModule input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled', true);
$(document).on('click', '.module input[type=checkbox]', function(event) {
  //check if checkbox is checked
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    //get closest .row and then find submodule checbox add false
    $(this).closest(".row").find(".subModule > input[type=checkbox]").attr("disabled", false);
  } else {
    //make disable..
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 mb-3">
  <!--added class-->
    <div class="d-block module">
      <input type="checkbox" name="module_access[{{ $key }}]" class="module-checkbox ml-2" value="1">somethins
    </div>
    <!--aded class-->
    <div class="d-block ml-4 mt-2 subModule">

      <input type="checkbox" name="module_access[{{ $key }}][{{ $index }}]" class="sub-module-checkbox ml-2" value="1">1
      <input type="checkbox" name="module_access[{{ $key }}][{{ $index }}]" class="sub-module-checkbox ml-2" value="1">2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 mb-3">
    <div class="d-block module" id="module">
      <input type="checkbox" name="module_access[{{ $key }}]" class="module-checkbox ml-2" value="1">somethins1
    </div>
    <div class="d-block ml-4 mt-2 subModule" id="subModule">

      <input type="checkbox" name="module_access[{{ $key }}][{{ $index }}]" class="sub-module-checkbox ml-2" value="1">1
      <input type="checkbox" name="module_access[{{ $key }}][{{ $index }}]" class="sub-module-checkbox ml-2" value="1">2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While retrieving, if I am checking if a module checkbox is selected or not, then that part is not working. Any idea?

if($('.module input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')){
            $(this).closest(".row").find(".subModule > input[type=checkbox]").attr("disabled", false);
        }

Comment: Yes you need to use `this` as selector which will refer to current module checkboxes .

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using a foreach, to define modules identified by #sameid (in your case id="module").

Ids are there to be unique, so your foreach is probably producing elements that have the same id and therefore the risk that your jquery will not work.